# iPhone - How to perform task in background?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5

I want to call a method in a regular time interval when the app is running in the background(minimize).

like i want to call web service daily....and want to show the result of this webService in the localNotification message body.
How to do this Task ?

Comment: I have a method and i want to call this method after every 2 minute when app is running in background(minimize).

Comment: the @selector works in the background so add a timer of 2 mins to that event .....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please follow this guide, provided from Apple, to see how applications enter the background:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html

Look for the section called **Background Execution and Multitasking**:

> However, you can only run specific kind of tasks in the background:
>
> - Apps that play audible content to the user while in the background, such as a music player app
> - Apps that keep users informed of their location at all times, such as a navigation app
> - Apps that support Voice over Internet Protocol (VoIP) Newsstand apps that need to download and process new content
> - Apps that receive regular updates from external accessories
>
> If your application falls within the grasp of these types, you can now proceed to determine the application type.
>
> The possible types are:
>
> - *audio*—The app plays audible content to the user while in the background. (This content includes streaming audio or video content
>     using AirPlay.)
> - *location*—The app keeps users informed of their location, even while it is running in the background.
> - *voip*—The app provides the ability for the user to make phone calls using an Internet connection.
> - *newsstand-content*—The app is a Newsstand app that downloads and processes magazine or newspaper content in the background.
> - *external-accessory*—The app works with a hardware accessory that needs to deliver updates on a regular schedule through the External
>     Accessory framework.
> - *bluetooth-central*—The app works with a Bluetooth accessory that needs to deliver updates on a regular schedule through the
>     CoreBluetooth framework.

Comment: If your App does not fall into the category, of the app types I listed in my answer, you can't do it. If your app is one of these categories, let me know which.

Comment: I updated my answer, to give you an idea of what types are availabe, for long-running background apps.

Comment: I'm painting a picture here. If your application does not fall into one of these types, it can't be done.

Comment: i have an array of WIFI networks name and i want to check that if presently available wifi is within my WIFI Networks array list then show alert.....i want this work when app is running or in background...

Comment: You could probably achieve this by using push notifications, maybe this will help: http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/programming-apple-push-notification-services

Comment: Thanks for your reply ...and i am trying this using local notification...is this possible..?

Comment: Yes, it can be done. There's a good article about it here:
http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/07/29/iphone-programming-tutorial-local-notifications/

Comment: i want to perform task periodically..when my app goes background.